# How can I watch videos of the presentations from DrupalCon Sydney for free?

Tags: files

I live too far away from Australia so I was unable to attend DrupalCon Sydney.  Is there any way to watch the videos online?  I tried looking on Blip.TV (where the videos for other DrupalCons are) but I couldn't find them.

Comment: I **HATE** that this has been closed rather than migrated. =@

Comment: @Chapabu I'm not sure that closing was the wrong action to be honest, but not for the usual reasons. I can understand the stigma attached to closures but I don't think any harm has actually been done this time round. The question/answer are very useful, and I'm certain won't be deleted, so others will get a chance to see them. If anything, the closure could be said to be stopping any new answers being posted, any of which would be useless (as the best possible answer has already been posted). There are a couple of re-open votes so it might well be re-opened organically anyway...

Comment: I'm torn (this is very useful information to me!) so I'm keeping out of it for now :)

Comment: I think this should be moved to chat, possible a new room.

Comment: @Chapabu The first rule is, "don't migrate crap."

Comment: @MPD That is not possible, yet. There is no way to move questions to chat rooms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, the DrupalCon Sydney videos are [on YouTube](http://sydney2013.drupal.org/download-drupalcon-sydney-sessions-youtube), not Blip.TV.  The link includes instructions for downloading the videos from YouTube, but if you want them all, it's probably easier to [use the torrent](http://cafuego.net/2013/02/15/drupalcon-sydney-session-video-torrent).

Comment: Thanks for the Torrent link :-) (I'm not going to lie - that feels weird saying that here)